# Swift: navigation bar item text and image

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to show image and text in navigation bar item.

```
func barItem() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "trashButtonItem.png"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Читать", for: .normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
        
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: button), animated: true);
}
```

In this case I have image on the left and text on the right. But I want to have image on the right and text on the left. How to do it?

Comment: You can add two uibarbbuttonitem with customview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the button semanticContentAttribute

```
func barItem() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "trashButtonItem.png"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Читать", for: .normal)
    button.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    button.sizeToFit()
        
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: button), animated: true);
}
```

You can also handle RTL

```
button.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared
    .userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `titleEdgeInsets` and the `imageEdgeInsets` of your UIButton.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]